# My rust macro doesn't want to accept this let statement

Tags: input, rust, syntax, macros, macro-rules

I've been trying to make a macro that functions similar to Python's input function.

Rather than write the stdin completely every time I wanted to automate it somewhat, and combine println! so I could kill 2 birds with one stone.

Essenitally, if someone passes in an argument it'll print a string then ask for input, if they don't it will just ask for input from the terminal.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! input {
    ($a:expr) => {
        println!("{}", $a);
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

        return $input
    };

    (_) => {
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut $input).unwrap();

        return $input
    };
}
```

I keep getting an error on the let statement and just don't know how to continue because I don't know the macro syntax well.

I posted the whole code block beacuse on the second match expression I was trying to make a match for when there were no arguments but i'm not sure if I did it correctly.

Sometimes the error messages brought me to github pages and I encounter randomed bugs, so i'm just confused how to continue furhter

It would be most appreciated if someone could help me fix the let statement, and i'd like to apologize for any inconvience.

Comment: Please include the *exact* error text.

Comment: What is `return $input` intending? Your variable is called `input`.

Comment: macro expansion ignores token `let` and any following
the usage of `input!` is likely invalid in expression context

Comment: I feel like the `return` is wrong; a macro isn't a function so it's not something you return from. Instead, it evaluates to a block of code

Comment: @tadman it intends to return the users input from the stdin

Comment: `$input` isn't a thing. `input` is the variable you captured that value into, and presumably should `return`. Get rid of all `$input` and replace with `input`.

Comment: @tadman I got rid of all the $ for input and removed the return's but the error text is the same

Comment: See my answer; you're also missing some braces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! input {
    ($a:expr) => {{
        println!("{}", $a);
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        input
    }};

    (_) => {{
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut $input).unwrap();

        input
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let foo = input!("Blargh");
}
```

You need the extra curly braces. The first pair is to enclose what the macro should expand to. The second pair is because the macro should expand to a **code block**.

Then we get rid of `return` because a macro isn't a function. Instead, it just expands to some code, and the value of a code block is just the last expression (without a `;`).

Comment: Thank you, I was really confused the moment I made contact with the macro syntax and you were really helpful @cadolphs, thank you.

I'll give you the checkmark when Stack Overflow lets me.

Comment: @cadolphs After seeing how it actually works, I think i'ma just use the regular print command honestly, maybe flush at the end if I can figure it out, thank you though.

Comment: Maybe what you want _is_ just a regular function?